# Using cut() with a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, histogram, distribution

The code below plots a histogram with shaded regions for 2 standard deviation less than mean, 1 standard deviation more than mean etc etc.

However, note that within some of the bins of the histogram, there are 2 different colours. Is it possible create bins that only contain 1 colour?

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10000, mean = 23, sd = 1))

ndist_probs <- c(0, 0.025, 0.16, 0.5, 0.84, 0.975, 1)

ndist_labels <- c("inf-2SD", "2-1SD", "1SD-mean", "mean-1SD", "1-2SD", "2SD-inf")

ndist_breaks <- quantile(df$x, ndist_probs)

df$ndist_breaks <- cut(df$x, breaks = ndist_breaks, ndist_labels)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill = ndist_breaks))
```

[image]

Comment: you would need to set the histogram breaks to align with your cut values. Not sure this can be done in geom_histogram, but you could precalculate and then use geom_bar

Comment: maybe `ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill = ndist_breaks), binwidth = 0.005)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could round your data to a single decimal.

```
df <- data.frame(x = round(rnorm(100000, mean = 23, sd = 1),1))
```

If you now set the binwidth in the histogram to 0.1 you get the desired result

```
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill = ndist_breaks),binwidth = 0.1)
```

[image]